# How to generate a thumbnail from a uploaded video in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, video-thumbnails

I am creating a api for social networking application and I need to create thumbnails from uploaded video files and then show it to the response. Here's my view

```
def get_queryset(self):
    video = self.queryset.values_list('video', flat=True).get(pk=12)
    ff = FFmpeg(inputs={video: None}, outputs={"media/"+video+"_thumbnail1.png": ['-ss', '00:00:4', '-vframes', '1']})
    #print(ff.cmd)
    ff.run()
    return Response({'video_thumbnail': video})
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: You aren't passing your video into FFmpeg `inputs={video: None}`

Comment: Actually, I take that back. It looks like ffmpy expects a dictionary with the string you want as a key. The hell? https://pypi.org/project/ffmpy/ Sorry about that.

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari The thumbnail is being created, getting this error now: object of type 'Response' has no len()

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the thumbnail you have created in the context of request

```
return Response({'video_thumbnail': video, "thumbnail_path": "media/"+video+"_thumbnail1.png" })
```

or you can configure `MEDIA_URL` setting and call it like this

```
<img src = {% media videoname_thumbnail.png %}>
```